# Authenticate a Springboot Application against another application using Basic Auth

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, spring-security, basic-authentication

How can I authenticate a Spring Boot application against a third party application?

According to the examples for implementing basic auth using spring security, the user and password are validated but I want to validate against a 200 response from another service. 
Here's how the user can be authenticated: 
User sends credentials with Basic Auth to access my SpringBoot REST service -> The SpringBoot service makes a GET request with basic auth header to a third party service -> receives a 200 OK and authenticate the end user to access all URLs on my REST service.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SpringSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationEntryPoint authEntryPoint;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and().httpBasic()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(authEntryPoint);
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER");
    }

}
```

Comment: What have you tried? - Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read our [ask] page for hints on how to improve your question.
Great question tend to provide quicker, better answers from the community

Comment: If you haven't already, you can also [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: I am a newbie to springboot. I am looking for examples to try.

Comment: Then this is not the site for it.  Please read our [ask] page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to implement your own [`AuthenticationProvider`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/authentication/AuthenticationProvider.html). For example:

```
public class ThirdPartyAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication auth) thows AuthenticationException {
        // call third party site with auth.getPrincipal() and auth.getCredentials() (those are username and password)
        // Throw AuthenticationException if response is not 200
        return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(...);
    }

    @Override
    public boolen supports(Class<?> authCls) {
        return UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class.equals(authCls);
    }
}
```

After that you can override the [`configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder)`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.html#configure-org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder-) method in your `SpringSecurityConfig`:

```
@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    // authProvider = instance of ThirdPartyAuthenticationProvider
    auth.authenticationProvider(authProvider); 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I got it to work using the UserDetailsService. I created a rest template and called my third party service to authenticate user and after receiving a response, the user can access all requests. This is how I did it:

SecurityConfig.java

```
    @Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationEntryPoint authEntryPoint;

    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated().and().httpBasic()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(authEntryPoint);

    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth, UserDetailsService userDetailsService)
            throws Exception {

        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    }
```

ABCUserDetails.java

```
    @Service("userDetailsService")
public class ABCUserDetails implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String abcuser) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Map<String, Object> userMap = userService.getUserByUsername(abcuser);

        // check if this user with this username exists, if not, throw an
        // exception
        // and stop the login process
        if (userMap == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User details not found : " + abcuser);
        }

        String username = (String) userMap.get("username");
        String password = (String) userMap.get("password");
        String role = (String) userMap.get("role");

        List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authList = getAuthorities(role);

        User user = new User(username, password, authList);

        return user;

    }

    private List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> getAuthorities(String role) {
        List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authList = new ArrayList<>();
        authList.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"));

        if (role != null && role.trim().length() > 0) {
            if (role.equals("myrole")) {
                authList.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN"));
            }
        }

        return authList;
    }
}
```

UserService.java

```
@Service("userService")
public class UserService {

    public Map<String, Object> getUserByUsername(String username) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Map<String, Object> userMap = null;
//get current request attributes
        ServletRequestAttributes attr = (ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes();

        String authToken = attr.getRequest().getHeader("Authorization");
        final String encodedUserPassword = authToken.replaceFirst("Basic" + " ", "");
        String usernameAndPassword = null;
        try {
            byte[] decodedBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(encodedUserPassword);
            usernameAndPassword = new String(decodedBytes, "UTF-8");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        final StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(usernameAndPassword, ":");
        final String username1 = tokenizer.nextToken();
        final String password = tokenizer.nextToken();
//thirdparty url
        final String uri = "http://abcurlauthprovider/userid="
                + "\"" + username1 + "\"";

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        try {
            HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
            headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
            headers.add("Authorization", "Basic " + encodedUserPassword);
            HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>("parameters", headers);
            ResponseEntity<String> mresponse = restTemplate.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class);

            if (username.equals(username1) || username.equals(username1)) {
                userMap = new HashMap<>();
                userMap.put("username", username1);
                userMap.put("password", password);
                userMap.put("role", (username.equals(username1)) ? username1 : username1);
                // return the usermap
                return userMap;
            }
        } catch (Exception eek) {
            System.out.println("** Exception: " + eek.getMessage());
        }

        return null;
    }

}
```

This is my AuthenticatioEntryPoint.java

```
    @Component
public class AuthenticationEntryPoint extends BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint {

    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException authEx)
            throws IOException, ServletException {

        response.addHeader("WWW-Authenticate", "Basic realm=" + getRealmName());
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
        PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
        writer.println("HTTP Status 401 - " + authEx.getMessage());

    }

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {

        System.out.println("----------------------inside afterPropertiesSet method");
        setRealmName("MYAPI");
        super.afterPropertiesSet();
    }}
```